# Makefile nothing to be done for xxx

Tags: javascript, unix, makefile, google-closure-compiler

I'm confused. I have seen some of the similar questions but none of them solve my problem; So I have this script I grabbed online that automatically compress javascript files by running makefile like this:

```
concatenated.min.js: file1.js file2.js
   java -jar ~/bin/compiler.jar $(addprefix --js=,$^) >$@
```

I have this make file here

```
JS_TARGETS = a.js b.js c.js d.js

CLOSURE = java -jar ~/bin/compiler.jar
CLOSURE_FLAGS = 

JS_MINIFIED = $(JS_TARGETS:.js=.min.js)
JS_GZIP = $(JS_TARGETS:.js=.js.gz)
JS_MIN_GZIP = $(JS_TARGETS:.js=.min.js.gz)

js: $(JS_TARGETS) $(JS_MINIFIED) $(JS_GZIP) $(JS_MIN_GZIP)

%.min.js: %.js
   $(CLOSURE) $(CLOSURE_FLAGS) --js=$< >$@
```

In the same directory as a.js, b.js, c.js, and d.js I have a file concat.min.js. Then, I ran `make concat.min.js` and the makefile gives me 'nothing to be done for concat.min.js'.

I also thought the problem was because i was missing the `$(addprefix --js=,$^) >$@` piece on the `%.min.js` rule. But it seems that it keeps giving me the same error even when I add it to the rule. did I do something wrong/typo? Thanks.

Comment: Are you *sure* you have a file called `a.js` in the directory you're calling `make` from? Make is clearly saying you don't.

Comment: yeah that one finally works. BUT my real objective is to concat them together, which still is not working..

Comment: "Nothing to be done" indicates that the target is newer than its dependencies, hence it doesn't need to be remade. If you want to recreate it unconditionally, make it a phony; if you have additional dependencies which Make doesn't know about, declare them in the Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the `%.min.js: %.js` line is saying is "if the file foo.js is newer than foo.min.js, then foo.min.js is out-of-date, and here's how to update it".  Therefore if you say `make a.min.js`, make will spot that you (presumably) don't have a `a.min.js` file, so it's certainly not newer than `a.js`, and so it'll make it using the command in the makefile.

The message you're getting is saying "you asked me to make concat.min.js, but there isn't a file concat.js which is newer than it, so... there's nothing to be done".

Looking at the rest of your question, I suspect you want something like:

```
concatenated.min.js: $(JS_TARGETS)
   java -jar ~/bin/compiler.jar $(addprefix --js=,$^) >$@
```

That makes sure that `concatenated.min.js` is newer than each of the files listed in `JS_TARGETS`.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you don't have concat.js file.